# A set of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem**: Let $E(x)$ be the number defined by the following expression
\begin{equation*}
 E(x)=\sqrt[3]\frac{x^3-3x+(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}+\sqrt[3]\frac{x^3-3x-(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2} 
\end{equation*}
where  $x$ is a real number and 
$\sqrt[3]{Z}$ denotes the real cubic root of the real number $Z$.

Determine the set
$ \{E(n); n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n > 1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let: $t=E(n)$ for some $n\gt 1$. So: $$t=\sqrt[3]{\frac {n^3-3n+(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac {n^3-3n-(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}}$$ From here: $$t^3=\frac {n^3-3n+(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}+\frac {n^3-3n-(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4}}{2}+3t\sqrt[3]{\frac {(n^3-3n+(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4})(n^3-3n-(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4})}{4}}$$ But: $$(n^3-3n+(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4})(n^3-3n-(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4})=(n^3-3n)^2-(n^2-1)^2(n^2-4)=n^6-6n^4+9n^2-(n^6-6n^4+9n^2-4)=4$$ Thus: $$t^3-3t-n^3+3n=0$$ Which means: $$(t-n)(t^2+n^2+tn-3)=0$$ But the equation: $t^2+n^2+tn-3=0$ hasn't real root for $n\gt 2$. And when $n=2$, we have: $$E(2)=2$$ And finally: $E(n)=n$ for every $n\gt 1$

Comment: An answer very "clean", as I told to Michael

Comment: Yes. it is clean as you told.

Comment: E(x) = x  is incredible at first sight, is not it?

Comment: Yes it is true for $|x|\ge 2$. And it's  incredible.

Answer (score -1):

$$E(x)^3=(Y+Z)^3=Y^3+3YZE(x)+Z^3\\
=x^3-3x+3E(x)\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^6-6x^4+9x^2-x^6+6x^4-9x^2+4}4}$$

Comment: Try, Michael, to simplify first, the answer is very "clean"

Comment: That's your job.

Comment: Excuse me, but in what terms does this answer the question?

Comment: $E^3-3E=x^3-3x$  I am sorry, @G.Sassatelli if you couldn't simplify the sextic under the square-root.  Perhaps you can solve this cubic?

Comment: Well... Jokes on me!